# Python go from a list of tuple to a list of integer without quotes

Tags: python, list, integer, quotes

I have this code :

```
selected_listbox_select_criteria_column = [('0', 'firstName'),('1', 'lastName'),('2', 'phone')]

column_to_check_for_criteria = []

column_to_check_for_criteria(', '.join(elems[0] for elems in selected_listbox_select_criteria_column))
```

It gives me this result :

```
['0,1,2']
```

How can I have a strict list of integer like this :

```
[0,1,2]
```

without the quotes to finally get equivalent of : `column_to_check_for_criteria = [0,1,2]`

Thanks

Comment: `int_list = [int(t[0]) for t in tuple_list]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is the additional work you don't need to be doing with your `', '.join(...)` call. It seems what you are trying to do is to simply extract in to a list the integer values as integer type from your list of tuples. To do this, based on the code you are writing, you don't need to use that `join`. You can simply use a list comprehension and cast each `elems[0]` to `int`. This should give you the expected output:

```
selected_listbox_select_criteria_column = [('0', 'firstName'),('1', 'lastName'),('2', 'phone')]

column_to_check_for_criteria = [int(elems[0]) for elems in selected_listbox_select_criteria_column]
```

Running that will now give you

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

As added information, you would typically use a `join` when you want to turn a list in to a string. An extra little note about using `join` is that expects an iterable of type `string` and not `int`. You can't actually use it on a list of integers. Observe the following two examples:

This will fail

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
print(",".join(a))
```

This will not

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(",".join(a))
```

Comment: Thanks for the details , I understand better thanks to you

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the original list using list comprehension and convert the first element in each tuple to integer using `int` function:

```
column_to_check_for_criteria = [int(i[0]) for i in selected_listbox_select_criteria_column]
```

Output: `[0, 1, 2]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can convert numbers (str) to int. Something like this:

```
selected_listbox_select_criteria_column = [('0', 'firstName'),('1', 'lastName'),('2', 'phone')]

column_to_check_for_criteria = [int(elems[0]) for elems in selected_listbox_select_criteria_column]
```

Answer (score 1):

using `map` you can achive this as

```
>>> tuple_list = [('0', 'firstName'),('1', 'lastName'),('2', 'phone')]
>>> int_list = list(map(lambda x : int(x[0]), tuple_list))
>>> int_list
[0, 1, 2]
```

more simple way will be use list comprehension as

```
int_list = [int(int_val) for int_val, string in tuple_list]
```